# Maven dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies, ejb, client

I have two projects:

- HelloWorldSessionBean2
- Client

I want to use classes from HelloWorldSessionBean2 in Client.

POM in HelloWorldSessionBean2:

```
(...)

<groupId>HelloWorldSessionBean2</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloWorldSessionBean2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

(...)
```

POM in client:

```
(...) 

<dependency>
    <groupId>HelloWorldSessionBean2</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorldSessionBean2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>ejb</type>
</dependency>

(...)
```

Unofortunatelly it doesn't work for me. During maven install show errors:
cannot find symbol ... (class from HelloWorldSessionBean2 project).
What I do wrong?

Comment: If the projects are somehow related to each other, I'd suggest you to create a parent POM module from which your both projects would inherit from. Otherwise you'd have to have your `HelloWorldSessionBean2` installed on your M2 repository in order for the Client to fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the projects are separate, you need to install the first project in your local .m2 repository so the other project can pick it up.  Any chance that there's an older version of the first project in your local repository that doesn't have the most recent changes?

If the two projects are being developed/managed on two different desktops, you'll need to manually install the project 1 jar into the second desktops local repo OR need to use a local artifact manager such as Nexus or Artifactory.

I guess I'm also not sure what ejb is going to do in a hello-world/non-JEE project.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem. In HelloWorldSessionBean2.jar will not be all classes.